# C# Selenium driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); ,Blocking operation

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

In C#, when calling `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()`, it sometimes blocks the execution of the code, with no reaction or errors, just a continuous blocking state.

I have tried replacing Selenium, but it didn't help. The browser I am using is Chrome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.